# Java completableFuture: how to parallelize several CompletableFutures

Tags: java, completable-future

Here my code:

```java
final int startIndex = LoaderConstants.ServeiTerritorial.DEFAULT_START_INDEX; 
final long pageSize = LoaderConstants.ServeiTerritorial.DEFAULT_PAGE_SIZE;
final String tableName = LoaderConstants.ServeiTerritorial.TIPUS_VIA_TABLE_NAME;
final String ownerType = LoaderConstants.ServeiTerritorial.TIPUS_VIA_OWNER_TYPE;

LongStream
    .iterate(1, n -> n <= 1000 / pageSize, n -> n+1)
    .mapToObj(pageNumber -> this.buildCompletableFutureOfResultSetType(tableName, ownerType, pageNumber * pageSize, pageSize))
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
```

What I'm trying to get is to parallelize each item.

First of all, for each page, I build a `CompletableFuture`:

```java
/**
* Builds a {@link CompletableFuture} in order to get oid.
*/
private CompletableFuture<ResultSetType> buildCompletableFutureOfResultSetType(
    final String tableName,
    final String owner,
    final long pageNumber,
    final long pageSize
) {
    Supplier<ResultSetType> supplier = () -> this.serveiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepository.getCataleg(tableName, null, owner, null, null, null, pageNumber, pageSize);

    return CompletableFuture.supplyAsync(supplier, this.servidorTerminologicExecutor);
}
```

I thought it was working fine, when I've realized that it's performed sequentially. Those are my logs:

```
2021-07-21 12:46:35.894 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,9ffb4627802548bf,9ffb4627802548bf,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-38] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Preparant crida a servei-territorial.getOid (oid: 2.16.724.4.402)
2021-07-21 12:46:35.895 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,9ffb4627802548bf,9ffb4627802548bf,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-38] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Creant petició cap a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>13801</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:35.896 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,9ffb4627802548bf,9ffb4627802548bf,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-38] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Enviant petició a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>13801</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:35.985 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,501c638f07534a0d,501c638f07534a0d,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-39] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Preparant crida a servei-territorial.getOid (oid: 2.16.724.4.402)
2021-07-21 12:46:35.986 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,501c638f07534a0d,501c638f07534a0d,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-39] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Creant petició cap a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>13901</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:35.987 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,501c638f07534a0d,501c638f07534a0d,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-39] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Enviant petició a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>13901</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:36.057 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,d840cc01f137b810,d840cc01f137b810,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-40] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Preparant crida a servei-territorial.getOid (oid: 2.16.724.4.402)
2021-07-21 12:46:36.058 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,d840cc01f137b810,d840cc01f137b810,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-40] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Creant petició cap a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>14001</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:36.061 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,d840cc01f137b810,d840cc01f137b810,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-40] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Enviant petició a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>14001</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:36.141 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,9ec5d6687eb6e9aa,9ec5d6687eb6e9aa,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-41] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Preparant crida a servei-territorial.getOid (oid: 2.16.724.4.402)
2021-07-21 12:46:36.142 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,9ec5d6687eb6e9aa,9ec5d6687eb6e9aa,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-41] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Creant petició cap a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>14101</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
2021-07-21 12:46:36.142 DEBUG [hes-mpi-imdg-loader,9ec5d6687eb6e9aa,9ec5d6687eb6e9aa,false] 22536 --- [ool-1-thread-41] ServeiTerritorialOidClientRepositoryImpl : Enviant petició a servei-territorial (request: <request><oid>2.16.724.4.402</oid><startIndex>14101</startIndex><pageSize>100</pageSize></request>)
```

I don't quite figure out what I'm doing wrong.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You're running this sequential stream with a `CompletableFutre.join` call in an intermediate step.

The problem is: elements traverse the (sequential) stream one at a time, and go through each step. This, of course, includes the `join()` call. That means that for each element, the entire operation (including the "async" part, `this.serveiTerritorialCatalegsClientRepository.getCataleg`) has to complete before the following element enters processing.

To solve this, force your pipeline to create futures for all elements before `join()` calls start being invoked. Something like this should work:

```
List<CompletableFuture<ResultSetType>> submittedTasks = LongStream
    .iterate(1, n -> n <= 1000 / pageSize, n -> n+1)
    .mapToObj(pageNumber -> this.buildCompletableFutureOfResultSetType(tableName, 
                                       ownerType, pageNumber * pageSize,
                                       pageSize))
    .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

That way, the terminal `collect()` will gather all submitted `CompletableFuture` objects without blocking. You don't need to collect to a list, but any terminal operation that is going to force the asynchronous tasks to be submitted should do; as long as you can manage to call `join` on each task separately.

After that, you can block, knowing that all asynchronous tasks have been started or at least queued.

```
submittedTasks.stream()
    .map(CompletableFuture::join)
    .forEach(...) //some terminal operation
```

This way, you avoid unnecessary blocking code.

---

I notice that I mentioned "sequential" a few times, but that's not to imply that running the same code on a parallel stream will solve it. The main problem will persist, although throughput may improve because you'd be *blocking in parallel*